# How do you concatenate in an input?

Tags: python

```
import msvcrt as m
def wait():
    m.getch()
strength = 10
health = 10
input("You now have",strength,"strength and",health,"health")
wait()
```

This is a slice of a project i'm working on and I have come across a seemingly unsolvable issue.
When this code is run, it should print ("You have now 10 strength and 10 health") but this is returned:

```
input("You now have",strength,"strength and",health,"health")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
```

I am absolutely baffled and I have tried many different things to fix this including adjusting the variables like: str(strength), (strength) and I tried replacing the commas with '+' but nothing seems to work and it stops my program from working properly.

Comment: `input` does not accept multiple arguments. You can create a string saying what you want and pass that as the argument, if you _actually_ need to use `input` for this.

Comment: Why are you using `input` instead of `print`?  Are you trying to get feedback from the user?  Seems like `print("You now have {0} strength and {1} health".format(str(strength), str(health)))` would work.

Comment: how about concatenating the string before you pass it to the `input`?  
like `input("You now have"+str(strength)+"strength and"+str(health)+"health")`

Comment: Thank you so much segFaulter. You guys helped me quite a bit as well as I realised that the wait() function is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter khelwood pointed out, you can't pass multiple parameters to the function `input`. However, adding your variables strength and health to strings won't directly work since the variables are of type int. So, try the following.

```
import msvcrt as m
def wait():
    m.getch()
strength = 10
health = 10
input("You now have "+str(strength)+" strength and "+str(health)+" health")
wait()
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
inputString = "You now have " + str(strength) + " strength and " + str(health) + " health"
input(inputString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to output the data that you are currently passing to `input`.

You can use string formatting in a `print` function to do so:

```
print('You now have {} strength and {} health'.format(strength, health))
```